# enable gzip compression on nginx give me long time server response

Tags: nginx, gzip, reverse-proxy

I have a web application running on a very low web server (CPU: ARM926EJ-S, RAM: 128MB), when I enabled gzip on nginx, I found that the server takes longer to respond, and I don't know if there is something wrong with the configuration.

**configuration:**

```
   gzip on;

   gzip_vary on;
   gzip_proxied any;
   gzip_comp_level 3;
   gzip_buffers 16 8k;
   gzip_http_version 1.1;
   gzip_min_length 256;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

**gizp enabled response time**
[image]

**gizp disabled response time**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following configurations have been tested and there are no problems with slowness or problems.

```
gzip on;
gzip_vary       on;
gzip_proxied    any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types 
 application/javascript
 ...
 ...
```

Comment: gzip_comp_level 6 will take longer than 3, I think the problem is because the CPU is too weak